# Difference between & (ampersand) and && or | (pipe) and || in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, operators

I wonder if Objective-C does care about whether I write & or &&? I believe one ampersand (&) would or should cause that if the LEFT side is already false, then the right side won't be evaluated.

Does this apply to Objective-C?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Yes.** The operators function identically in C and Objective-C.

Just like in C (or C++, if you're using Objective-C++) `&` and `|` are bit-wise and `&&` and `||` are logical (and short-circuit). Bit-wise operators (`&` and `|`) are *not* short-circuit.

See [Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Comment: So I just got that the wrong way around. && will not evaluate the right side when the left is already false, but & will evaluate both anyways. correct?

Comment: And && has a boolean result, while & does not.

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C uses the C bitwise and logical operators (& is bitwise and && is logical). The single & will evaluate both expressions.