# Perform segue after Login successful in Storyboards

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have 2 `UITextFields`, one of them for Login and the another for the Password.

Only if the Login is "succesful", I want to perform the `Segue` with `Push` to another `View Controller`. But when I touch the button, directly the View push to the Another View without check the Condition.

In StoryBoard I drag from the UIButton to the View Controller I want to push, for creating the segue with push option.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonLogin:(id)sender {
    if (([self.textFieldLogin.text isEqualToString:@"User"]) && ([self.textFieldPassword.text isEqualToString:@"1515"])){

       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueLogin" sender:self];

    }else{
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"User wrong"
                                                      message:@"Fill up again the user info"
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to drag the segue from the overall `UIViewController` to the next `UIViewController`, i.e. you shouldn't specifically connect the `UIButton` (or any IBOutlet for that matter) to the next `UIViewController` if the transition's conditional.

Like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong logical operator.

User `&&`instead of `&` inside your if statement.

For better understand of the difference between the two I recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239897/difference-between-ampersand-and-or-pipe-and-in-objective-c) other stack overflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**
You can still link UIButton to the View Controller and create a Segue. If your login is successful then invoke self.performSegue within your closure. Something like this...

```
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        authenticateUser(email: email.text!, password: password.text!)
}

func authenticateUser(email: String, password: String){
        # Building your loginUrl goes here

        Alamofire.request(loginUrl!,
                          method: .post,
                          parameters: nil,
                          encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                          headers: headers)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
                switch(response.result) {
                case .success(_):

                    let apiResponse : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                    print("Now Performing Segue on IBAction Pressed")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDashboard", sender: self)
                   break

                case .failure(_):
                    print(response.result.error)
                    break
                }
            }
    }
```