# iOS First Launch show Terms and Conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

i need help with the following code. My aim is to show the UIViewController "Terms" (already exists in my Storyboard and I have asigned the name Terms in the Storyboard ID). If the app as already been opened and the user accepted the T&C then show the normal UIViewController.

FIRSTVIEWCONTROLLER.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@end

@interface First : UIViewController

@end

@interface Terms: UIViewController

@end
```

FIRSTVIEWCONTROLLER.M

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad: (BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    BOOL isAccepted = [standardUserDefaults boolForKey:@"iHaveAcceptedTheTerms"];

    if (!isAccepted) {
        [self presentViewController:Terms animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:First animated:YES];
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

As it is, I am receiving 2 errors: "Unexpected interface name 'Terms'/'First': expected expression".

Please take a look at the storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi6aT.png

Help me please. xcode beginner.

Comment: Where are you seeing the errors? Point out the exact code giving you the problem.

Comment: Your storyboard looks weird because you don't have an arrow going to the terms and you have lots of arrows going to the tab bar controller. It all seems inverted (but I don't know what its intended to do). If a beginner with XCode/storyboards start with one view controller, run it, then add another and run again, then add another and run again etc. Build it up bit by bit slowly

Comment: @rmaddy the error appears on `[self presentViewController:Terms animated:YES completion:nil];` and on `[self.navigationController pushViewController:First animated:YES];` Thank you.

Comment: You are trying to pass the names of the classes instead of creating instances of the view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

First off, remove these lines from your .h since they're unnecessary:

```
@interface First : UIViewController

@end

@interface Terms: UIViewController

@end
```

Secondly, your Storyboard doesn't look quite right... From the `FirstViewController`, you need to create segues between the view and both potential subsequent view controllers, i.e. "First" and "Terms", using the method I've specified here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20690072/2274694; then label those segues with identifiers.

That way, if you want to segue to the pertinent view controller depending on whether or not the terms have already been accepted, you could perform the segue using the relevant identifier, ex:

```
if (!isAccepted) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"firstSegue" sender:self];
} else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"termsSegue" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Where will the "termsSegue" start? I mean from which action?

Comment: Don't connect it to a specific action within the storyboard... Just create a general segue.  I explain how in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20690072/2274694 . That way, the segue will happen where you've specified in your viewDidLoad.