# Navigate view to another view upon login success

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

When the user logins with his Facebook account i want to navigate to another view. Currently upon successful login the user is in the same view.
I want the view to navigate to `DashBoardViewController`.

However, if you look closer at my Storyboard- viewcontroller. There's a `view` (That's used for FB login button), instead of a button. Therefore, i am not able to link it to the  `DashBoardViewController`.

Can someone help me out, so upon successful user login the user navigates to `DashBoardViewController`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't want to link the button directly to the next view anyway... You'll want to create your segue link so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20690072/2274694 since you only want to login conditionally...that is only if the login is successful.

Comment: I don't have any IBOutlets to connect. There's just a  view there.

Comment: That answer has nothing to do with IBOutlets though... The point is that you don't need to connect the login button directly. The connection needs to come from the general view controller...not a particular outlet.

Answer (score 0):

How about pushing to dashboard when you successfully login?

```
DashViewController *dashController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DashView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dashController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Doing this brings the login screen back to the UIView that made the request instead of taking the user directly to the next view in the flow.